# Connecting an Access database to a SQL Server back end outside of an intranet

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, iis-7, ms-access-2013

I have linked a MSAccess database to SQL Server via an Intranet on many occasions.

Is it possible to link a MSAccess database to a SQL Server outside of an Intranet?  In other words, can I have a MSAccess database that I send to a friend, and when they open the database it will connect to a SQL Server that's operating on my IIS?

Comment: You can do it if you are on same LAN or a site connected via VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible and actually very easy. You just need to know the IP address of your SQL Server. Then, in MS Access, you need to create a linked table which references this SQL Server.

However, you need to open the ports of your SQL Server for the public internet, and this is not recommended. At least you should restrict the port to the IP address of your friend.